# Empty remote repository and push my current local repo into it

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a gitlab repository that just had two minor commits which are not important. Now we want to push a local app I have in my machine which to replace all of the contents of the remote repo.

So what would be the best strategy for achieving this? Undoing all commits in the remote repo and then link my local to the remote repo and doing a push? or any easier way?

Comment: Why do you want to delete the history in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Two alternatives:

1. delete and recreate the entire project, or
2. unprotect the `master` branch and force push to it from the new repo

   ```
   git push origin master --force
   ```

Comment: Or you delete master and push a new master. So you don't have to force-push.

Comment: To delete `master` in the GUI you'd have to unprotect it and have another branch that you can select as default branch. Only after that you can delete it. Force push seems easier to me.